# If a continuous function on $\mathbb R$ satisfies $f(x)\ge x^2$, it attains its minimum

Tags: calculus, functions, optimization

This question is from my homework and I don't know how to prove it.

> Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function at $\mathbb{R}$. prove that if $f(x)\geq x^2$ to every $x$ in  $\mathbb{R}$, then $f(x)$ gets minimum on $[0,\infty)$.

Thank you in advanced for clues or help.

Comment: Since, $ f(x): \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ and $ x^2 \ge 0, \forall x $

Comment: if $x^2$ has minimum 0 , how can it relate that $f(x)$ has minimum? I don't understand the logic in it.@hjpotter92

Comment: because $f(x)$ has been given to _always be_ $\ge x^2$.

Comment: Andre's answer is correct. The other comments don't seem to recognize the subtlety that $f(x) \ge x^2$ ensures that $f(x)$ is a *proper* continuous function, which is the key assumption (together with non-negativity) that ensures that it actually attains its infimum.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(0)=a$.  Note that $a\ge 0$.

Now restrict our function to the closed interval $[0,\sqrt{a}]$. Since $f$ is continuous, by a standard theorem $f$ attains a minimum on $[0,\sqrt{a}]$. Since $f(x)\gt a$ when $x\gt \sqrt{a}$, this minimum is a global minimum on $[0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

The function $f(x)$ has a lower bond since $x^2\geq 0\implies f(x)\geq x^2\geq0$ which means $f(x)\geq0$.From this we know the function has a minimum cause it's co-domain is restricted from below.Clearly since $f(x)\geq 0$ the minimum is between $[0,+\infty)$

Comment: This is not correct. If you only assume $f(x) \ge 0$, then it does not follow that $f$ attains its infimum; consider, for instance, $f(x) = e^{-x}$.